# how to make Google Mapview change to fullscreen from a smaller mapview?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a Google mapview in the corner of the screen. I want to add an event that makes it go fullscreen with a button on the map interface, and then small screen again with the same button. Any ideas??

Android v4.0.4
Google Map API V2

Comment: Can you post your layout XML?

Comment: set fragement width and height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by 2 way:

1. create a new `Activity` that on the press of a button will start of and will include a full screen map. in this activity create the same button that will bring you back to your original `Activity`.
2. you can programaticly change the Layout width a length of you `MapFragment` in the same window.

second option will be better as you would avoid the screen flickering of new activity loading.

**UPDATE:**

regarding the second option here is a code i wrote to enlarge map onClick of the map see if this helps you:

```
 @Override
 public void onMapClick(LatLng point) 
{
    LinearLayout mapFrameLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mapFrameLayout);

    if (!isMapOpen)     
    {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams fullMapParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        if (!isDetailsOpen)
        {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.hide(closedDetailsFragment).commit();
            mapFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(fullMapParams);
            isMapOpen = true;
            isDetailsOpenWhenOpenedMap = false;
        }
        else
        {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.hide(openedDetailsFragment).commit();
            mapFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(fullMapParams);
            isMapOpen = true;
            isDetailsOpenWhenOpenedMap = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams defaultMapparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 280);
        mapFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(defaultMapparams);
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        if (isDetailsOpenWhenOpenedMap)
        {
            fragmentTransaction.show(openedDetailsFragment).commit();               
        }
        else
        {
            fragmentTransaction.show(closedDetailsFragment).commit();
        }
        isMapOpen = false;
    }
}
```

as you see i change the size of the `FrameLayout` where the map sits, you can put in the same layout your button and place it on the right|top corner for example. when your map will stretch the button will still be at the same right|top corner.

Comment: @EmilAdz can u explain 2nd option a bit in details if u consider it better then Activity? Where it will be his return button? It should be generated at resize time no? How returning to previous state should be done? what happen with button in that moment? What u mean by screen flickering? 10q

Answer (score 0):

Start new activity on click with full screen map and all buttons/functions u need there.. Pass requered parameters using putExtra on starting intenet (location coordinates for example) and voila.. ;)